What is the name of this photography framing tool
I am looking for the name of a very simple and basic tool for teaching photography, but I can't find the name or photoreferences. It is used for compositing and framing a pic analogically.
The tool works like the hands of this example:

Also if there are videotutorials for a DIY school project would be grateful. I hope someone can help.

Might be better to ask this in Photography Stack Exchange.  Couldn't you just cut a rectangle out of a piece of cardboard?

That specific tool is called... finger framing (as far as I know)
It has at least two more advanced devices:
Cardboard or paper viewfinder. (Probably this is the one you are searching)
You can use one "static", where a rectangular hole on a cardboard (normally black) has the same aspect ratio on your camera.
If you additionally make the rectangle the same size as your camera's sensor (or using metric units) you can use it to determine the focal length. See this: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/114811/framing-shots-before-purchasing-cameras/114813#114813
I recommend having static pieces of cardboard. But you can use two L-shaped cardboards to have different aspect ratios.
A more advanced device is a Director's Viewfinder.
https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=directors+viewfinder

Thanks. That is the name I was looking for. Do you know if it is also called "passepartout" in English, French and/or Spanish?

But that is for framing the end result, a printed image. Also is called "Monalisa" in Spanish. This is a generous white (black or whatever) space between the picture and the "real" frame.
